# OneLogin SAML2 Invalid Schema

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am in the process of integrating OneLogin for SAML2 authentication. I have this working just fine in our QA servers but my production environment is throwing an error.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in 

\Classes\OneLogin\src\Saml2\Utils.php on line 133
invalid_response

OneLogin\Saml2\Auth Object
(
    [_settings:OneLogin\Saml2\Auth:private] => OneLogin\Saml2\Settings Object
        (
            [_paths:OneLogin\Saml2\Settings:private] => Array
                (
                    [base] => \\Classes\OneLogin/
                    [config] => \\Classes\OneLogin/
                    [cert] => \\Classes\OneLogin/certs/
                    [lib] => \\Classes\OneLogin/src/
                )

            [_baseurl:OneLogin\Saml2\Settings:private] => 
            [_strict:OneLogin\Saml2\Settings:private] => 1
            [_debug:OneLogin\Saml2\Settings:private] => 
            [_sp:OneLogin\Saml2\Settings:private] => Array
                (
                    [entityId] => tools
                    [assertionConsumerService] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://example.com/login/saml2.php
                            [binding] => urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                        )

                    [NameIDFormat] => urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
                    [x509cert] => -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

From what it sounds like, the invalid schema is due to the response coming back? It must not be in the expected format that matches the .xsd?

If thats the case, this this usually be an indication of an invalid certificate?

```
    $settingsInfo = array(
    'strict' => true,
    'sp' => array(
        'entityId' => 'tools',
        'assertionConsumerService' => array(
            'url' => "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
        ),
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
        'x509cert' => file_get_contents('lb-sso.pem', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH),
        'privateKey' => file_get_contents('lb-sso.key', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH),
    ),
    'idp' => array(
        'entityId' => 'https://sso.example.com',
        'singleSignOnService' => array(
            'url' => 'https://sso.example.com/idp/SSO.saml2',
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ),
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            'url' => 'https://sso.example.com/idp/SSO.saml2',
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ),
        'x509cert' => file_get_contents('sso.pem', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)
    ),
    'compress' => array(
        'requests' => true,
        'responses' => true
    ),
    'security' => array(
        'authnRequestsSigned' => true,
        'signatureAlgorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256',
    )
);

$auth = new OneLogin\Saml2\Auth($settingsInfo);
```

**Update:**

I was able to print out some additional errors for this.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in \\Classes\OneLogin\src\Saml2\Utils.php on line 134 

failed to load external entity "/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" 
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location '/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'. Skipping the import. 
failed to load external entity "/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xenc-schema.xsd" 
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location '/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xenc-schema.xsd'. Skipping the import. 
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData' does not resolve to a(n) element declaration. 
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedKey' does not resolve to a(n) element declaration.
```

The files xsd files do exist however the path appears to be possibly missing another `/` in front of it. `//Classes/OneLogin/...`

**Update 2:**

It appears there could be a difference of how idp is sending back the response to our production server verses our QA server.

The OneLogin files are identical on both sites but I had to toggle one setting in the security side of things `wantXMLValidation = false`.

This leads me to believe that the XML format they are sending back for the response doesn't match the same xsd format that is expected.

It shows that the authentication and certificates are all valid and the connection is being established, just no longer validating the format of the XML.

What security implications can this have if any or is it more of a housekeeping check to make sure it is including all of the expected nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The SAMLResponse proccesed by the php-saml toolkit does not follows the xsd schema, that why you see that error.

You can try record the SAMLResponse with SAMLTracer and later use https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php to get the cause of the XML invalidation

Comment: I pasted the XML response from the SAML tracer and I got "THE XML IS VALID."

Comment: Made an edit - found some additional errors that might help out.